# Doctrine custom mapping type brings database errors

Tags: doctrine-orm, mapping, postgis, raster

I'm trying to realize an Raster-functionality in PostGis with a custom mapping type. To add a Raster to the Database,

I am creating a table with a column of type raster. 
To insert Raster-Data I'm inserting a new empty Raster with st_makeemptyraster, add a new Band with st_addband and set the values with st_setvalues.

So, this could be done in PLAIN SQL in that way:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rasters (id serial, rast raster);
INSERT INTO rasters(id,rast)
VALUES(
    3, 
    st_setvalues(
        st_addband(     
            ST_MakeEmptyRaster( 2, 2, 0.0005, 0.0005, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4326),
            1,
            '32BF',
            1,
            0
        ),
        1,
        1,
        1,
        ARRAY[[9, 9], [9, 9]]::double precision[][]
     )
);
```

Now I have tried to add a custom mapping type for raster in doctrine.

I have added an entity Raster:

```
<?php
/**
 * More Documentation here:
 *
 * http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/RT_ST_MakeEmptyRaster.html
 *
 * raster ST_MakeEmptyRaster(raster rast);
 * raster ST_MakeEmptyRaster(integer width, integer height, float8 upperleftx, float8 upperlefty, float8 scalex, float8 scaley, float8 skewx, float8 skewy, integer srid=unknown);
 * raster ST_MakeEmptyRaster(integer width, integer height, float8 upperleftx, float8 upperlefty, float8 pixelsize);
 *
 *
 * http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/RT_ST_AddBand.html
 *
 *
 */
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;
use AppBundle\Model\Raster as RasterModel;
/**
 * Raster
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\RasterRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="rasters")
 */
class Raster
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var RasterModel $raster
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="rast", type="raster", nullable=true)
     */
    private $raster;
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Set raster
     *
     * @param RasterModel $raster
     *
     * @return Raster
     */
    public function setRaster(RasterModel $raster)
    {
        $this->raster = $raster;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get raster
     *
     * @return Raster
     */
    public function getRaster()
    {
        return $this->raster;
    }
}
```

The php-Object of the Model:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Model;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * Raster
 */
class Raster
{
    /**
     * @var Raster $raster
     */
    private $raster;
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $width;
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $height;
    /**
     * @var float
     */
    private $upperLeftX;
    /**
     * @var float
     */
    private $upperLeftY;
    /**
     * @var float
     */
    private $scaleX;
    /**
     * @var float
     */
    private $scaleY;
    /**
     * @var float
     */
    private $skewX;
    /**
     * @var float
     */
    private $skewY;
    /**
     * @var float
     */
    private $pixelSize;
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $srid;
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection RasterBand
     */
    private $bands;
    /**
     * Raster constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bands = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * @return Raster
     */
    public function getRaster()
    {
        return $this->raster;
    }
    /**
     * @param Raster $raster
     * @return Raster
     */
    public function setRaster($raster)
    {
        $this->raster = $raster;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getWidth()
    {
        return $this->width;
    }
    /**
     * @param int $width
     * @return Raster
     */
    public function setWidth($width)
    {
        $this->width = $width;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getHeight()
    {
        return $this->height;
    }
    /**
     * @param int $height
     * @return Raster
     */
    public function setHeight($height)
    {
        $this->height = $height;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getUpperLeftX()
    {
        return $this->upperLeftX;
    }
    /**
     * @param float $upperLeftX
     * @return Raster
     */
    public function setUpperLeftX($upperLeftX)
    {
        $this->upperLeftX = $upperLeftX;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getUpperLeftY()
    {
        return $this->upperLeftY;
    }
    /**
     * @param float $upperLeftY
     * @return Raster
     */
    public function setUpperLeftY($upperLeftY)
    {
        $this->upperLeftY = $upperLeftY;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getScaleX()
    {
        return $this->scaleX;
    }
    /**
     * @param float $scaleX
     * @return Raster
     */
    public function setScaleX($scaleX)
    {
        $this->scaleX = $scaleX;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getScaleY()
    {
        return $this->scaleY;
    }
    /**
     * @param float $scaleY
     * @return Raster
     */
    public function setScaleY($scaleY)
    {
        $this->scaleY = $scaleY;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getSkewX()
    {
        return $this->skewX;
    }
    /**
     * @param float $skewX
     * @return Raster
     */
    public function setSkewX($skewX)
    {
        $this->skewX = $skewX;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getSkewY()
    {
        return $this->skewY;
    }
    /**
     * @param float $skewY
     * @return Raster
     */
    public function setSkewY($skewY)
    {
        $this->skewY = $skewY;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getPixelSize()
    {
        return $this->pixelSize;
    }
    /**
     * @param float $pixelSize
     * @return Raster
     */
    public function setPixelSize($pixelSize)
    {
        $this->pixelSize = $pixelSize;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSrid()
    {
        return $this->srid;
    }
    /**
     * @param int $srid
     * @return Raster
     */
    public function setSrid($srid)
    {
        $this->srid = $srid;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getBands()
    {
        return $this->bands;
    }
    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $bands
     * @return Raster
     */
    public function setBands($bands)
    {
        $this->bands = $bands;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @param RasterBand $band
     * @return array|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function addBand(RasterBand $band)
    {
        $this->bands[] = $band;
        return $this->bands;
    }
    /**
     * @param RasterBand $band
     * @return $this
     */
    public function removeBand(RasterBand $band)
    {
        $this->bands->removeElement($band);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And the custom mapping type:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
class RasterType extends Type
{
    const RASTER = 'raster';
    public function getName()
    {
        return self::RASTER;
    }
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return 'raster';
    }
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        /**
         * ToDo: Finish implementing it
         */
        return new \AppBundle\Model\Raster();
    }
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return sprintf('%d, %d, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %d', 10, 10, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 4269);
    }
    public function canRequireSQLConversion()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function convertToPHPValueSQL($sqlExpr, $platform)
    {
        /**
         * ToDo: Finish implementing it
         */
        return sprintf('AsText(%s)', $sqlExpr);
    }
    public function convertToDatabaseValueSQL($sqlExpr, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return sprintf('st_makeemptyraster(%s)', $sqlExpr);
    }
}
```

In my first intent I'm trying to add a empty raster to the database.
Instead of inserting or updating the raster, the following error appears:

```
2) AppBundle\Tests\Entity\RasterTest::testCreateEmptyRasterAndAddBand
Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO rasters (id, rast) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [2, "st_makeemptyraster(10, 10, 0.100000, 0.100000, 0.100000, 0.100000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 4269)"]:

SQLSTATE[XX000]: Internal error: 7 ERROR:  rt_raster_from_wkb: wkb size (46)  < min size (61)
```

The same data as a plain SQL-Query works fine:

```
INSERT INTO rasters (id, rast) VALUES (14, st_makeemptyraster(10, 10, 0.100000, 0.100000, 0.100000, 0.100000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 4269)); 
INSERT 0 1
```

Does anybody has an idea how to get this fixed?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm not able to comment with my reputation less than 50. So I just can write an answere. Some mod may change it to a comment instead?)

I'm not familar with Doctrine but in first place I have an assumption to a common problem.

Can you assure that passing values to any query isn't affected by a string conversion before the query will be built? Executing a query with arguments may convert them to string values with escaped characters to avoid security issues.

An example:

`$yourDoctrineAdapter->executeInsert( 42, "storedProcedureCall( 'foo' )" );`

may result in something like

`INSERT INTO foo ( bar, baz ) VALUES ( '42', 'storedProcedureCall( \'foo\' )' );`

My second assumption is about the internal error message and not about a wrong type.

`rt_raster_from_wkb: wkb size (46)  < min size (61)`.

I don't know what's the return value of `st_makeemptyraster()` but your call from Doctrine may still results in a string argument instead a stored function call. The value inserted in the column `rast` is type boxed and then the WKB size of the stringified "call" is less than the WKB size of the stored function return value of `st_makeemptyraster()`.

I suggest to digg into something like 'how to execute stored function calls with doctrine'.